# Plot a fitted curve on percentage histogram (not the actual data)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, curve-fitting

I first try to draw my data as percentage as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
plt.hist(data, weights=np.ones(len(data)) / len(data), bins=5)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This will give me this.
[image]

Now I used this line to fit a curve on the "percentage data" as follows :

```
import seaborn as sns
p=sns.displot(data=data, x="Dist",kde=True, bins=5)
```

Which gives me this:
[image]

But this curve was fitted according to the data not the percent per 5 bins. If for example you had 10 bins you could understand why there was a bump at the end. That bump we don't want to see. What I really want is a curve as this

[image]

Comment: You forgot to include reproducible data.  You could try to increase the bandwidth of the kde, e.g. `sns.histplot(data=data, x="Dist", kde=True, stat='percent', bins=5, kde_kws={'bw_adjust': 3})`

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for your comment. I added the data at the end. Even though changing the bandwidth would make the end more smoother but it will make the beginning incorrect: the summit is much lower than the actual data.

Comment: @JohanC I was wondering if there is any other way? Say fitting data while using plt.hist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kde plot approximates the data as a sum of guassian bell curves.
An idea could be to regroup the data and place them at the centers of each bar.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

z = [1.83E-05,2.03E-05,3.19E-05,3.39E-05,3.46E-05,3.56E-05,3.63E-05,3.66E-05,4.13E-05,4.29E-05,4.29E-05,4.79E-05,5.01E-05,5.07E-05,5.08E-05,5.21E-05,5.39E-05,5.75E-05,5.91E-05,5.95E-05,5.98E-05,6.00E-05,6.40E-05,6.41E-05,6.67E-05,6.79E-05,6.79E-05,6.92E-05,7.03E-05,7.17E-05,7.45E-05,7.75E-05,7.99E-05,8.03E-05,8.31E-05,8.74E-05,9.69E-05,9.80E-05,9.86E-05,0.000108267,0.000108961,0.000109634,0.000111083,0.000111933,0.00011491,0.000126831,0.000135493,0.000138174,0.000141792,0.000150507,0.000155346,0.000155516,0.000202407,0.000243149,0.000248106,0.00025259,0.000254496,0.000258372,0.000258929,0.000265318,0.000293665,0.000312719,0.000430077]

counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(z, 5)
centers = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2
regrouped_data = np.repeat(centers, counts)

sns.histplot(data=regrouped_data, kde=True, bins=bin_edges)
```

[image: sns.histplot using regrouped data for kde]

Normally, a kdeplot can be extended via the `clip=` parameter, but unfortunately `kde_kws={'clip':bin_edges[[0,-1]]}` doesn't work here.
To extend the kde, a trick could be to keep the highest and lowest value of the original data.  So, subtracting one of the counts of the first and last bin, and append the lowest and highest value to the regrouped data.

```py
counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(z, 5)
centers = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2
counts[[0, -1]] -= 1
regrouped_data = np.concatenate([np.repeat(centers, counts), bin_edges[[0, -1]]])

sns.histplot(data=regrouped_data, kde=True, bins=bin_edges, stat='percent')
```

[image: extending the kde till the first and last value]

Comment: Thank you for your time. I marked it as correct but still it would not be 100 percent correct as it is changing the actual percentage. For example the true percentage for the first bin is 60 percent but what you did would make it as 40 percent. What I wanted is to fit a beta distribution or something to the "percent data"

Comment: You can use `sns.histplot(..., stat='percent')` if you want to see percentages instead of counts.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to have the curve fully fit the first bin?

Comment: Adding the minimum of `z` to the regrouped data extends the kde, but also lowers the first peek a bit. Drawing the kde separately doesn't scale the kde to the height of the percentage histogram.